# Reading an env secret inside of a Cloudflare Workers Serverless Function

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, serverless, cloudflare-workers

This is a seemingly trivial request, but does anyone know how to read the worker secrets inside of a cloudflare function? I see a lot of conflicting advise and the Cloudflare documentation doesn't really show to use it in a real world example.

Answer (score 2):

The secrets get sent in the `env` object of the `fetch` in your serverless function, per [Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/configuration/environment-variables/#add-environment-variables-via-wrangler). So if you add that param to your fetch, they kind of magically show up on there.

The naming structure of the env variables is custom. You set it up yourself. `API_KEY` in my example is what I was using as the name for my secret (yours can be whatever you'd like).

Cloudflare doesn't really show you a whole example. My code sample below is getting invoked from a webhook, ingests that data payload from that webhook and then fires off a data payload to an API endpoint. Your data shape is likely different to what is shown here so be sure to adjust as needed:

```js
export default {
  async fetch(request, env) {
    if (request.method === 'POST') {
      const webhookData = await request.json();

      if (webhookData.event === 'your.param.here') {
        const memberInfo = webhookData.payload;

        const apiData = {
          apikey: env.API_KEY,  // Use the secret here
          email: memberInfo.email,
        };

        // Make the API call
        const apiResponse = await fetch('https://your.endpoint.here/v1/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify(apiData)
        });

        if (apiResponse.ok) {
          // API request was successful
          return new Response('Webhook received and API request sent!', { status: 200 });
        } else {
          // API request failed
          console.error('API request failed:', await apiResponse.text());
          return new Response('An error occurred.', { status: 500 });
        }
      } else {
        // Not the event we're interested in
        return new Response('Event not handled.', { status: 200 });
      }
    } else {
      return new Response('Expected a POST request.', { status: 400 });
    }
  }
}
```